# If Windows 10 Power Shell shows get-tpm with all "false", and bios is up to date, it means I can't have it?

Tags: windows, tpm, dell-g3

I'm looking to update my Windows 10 to 11. Now I need this "TPM" thing.

I have a Dell G3, I updated the bios using the SupportAssist, but when I type on powershell > "get-tpm" I see:

```
TpmPresent                : False
TpmReady                  : False
TpmEnabled                : False
TpmActivated              : False
TpmOwned                  : False
RestartPending            : False
ManufacturerId            : 0
ManufacturerIdTxt         :
ManufacturerVersion       :
ManufacturerVersionFull20 :
ManagedAuthLevel          : Full
OwnerAuth                 :
OwnerClearDisabled        : True
AutoProvisioning          : NotDefined
LockedOut                 : False
LockoutHealTime           :
LockoutCount              :
LockoutMax                :
SelfTest                  :
```

Is there anything else I can do here? TPM is not in my up to date bios options as well.

Comment: It means that the fTPM is disabled if Dell even allows it to be enabled

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it means you do not have TPM.  Recheck your BIOS (UEFI) settings, but I am sure that will just confirm the answer you got above.

I just replaced a machine without TPM with one that does have TPMv2 and it is running Windows 11.

Unless the motherboard has a TPM header, there is not much you can do. Large manufacturers tend to either include TPM or not include TPM.

Comment: “Unless the motherboard has a TPM header, …” - The authors CPU is 8th Generation, which supports Intels fTPM functionality, provided it can be enabled on Dell hardware. A TPM header isn’t necessarily required if it can be enabled

Answer (score 0):

The only way to tell for sure is to boot in to the BIOS and [follow the manufacturers instructions for enabling the TPM](https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-us/000189676/windows-10-how-to-enable-the-tpm-trusted-platform-module).

Do not trust Windows or `Get-Tpm` as I have seen `Get-Tpm` return `False` on a system that not only had a working TPM but was also using BitLocker, which would lock your bits if the TPM was suddenly gone.

Your computer should have a TPM in it. If you don't see the options in BIOS, peform a BIOS update using Dell Command Update and then check again.

From DELL:

> To activate the TPM on your Dell computer in BIOS, perform the
> following steps.
>
> ```
> Reboot your computer.
> Press F2 once a second when the Dell logo appears.
> Once in the BIOS refer to the section that corresponds to the brand of your computer, for more instructions.
> ```
>
> NOTES:
>
> ```
> Depending on your computer model you may be able to navigate BIOS using your mouse. If not, navigate with the up or down, and left or
> ```
>
> right arrow keys, and use the Enter key to select options.
> The menu options may vary depending on the computer model.
>
> Select Security. Switch the toggle under Intel Platform Trust
> Technology to On. NOTE: For computers that have the Aptio Setup
> Utility perform the following steps (look in the upper right corner to
> see if your computer uses it).
>
> ```
> Select Firmware TPM.
> Ensure Enabled is selected (use the up or down arrows as needed), and then press the Enter key.
> ```
>
> Select Apply Changes. NOTE: For computers that have the Aptio Setup
> Utility perform the following steps.
>
> ```
> Press the F10 key.
> Select Yes to save and exit, and then press the Enter key.
> ```
>
> Select Exit (when available). NOTE: The computer will reboot to the
> Windows desktop.